# Serialize and Deserialize a custom tensorflow model which can be loaded back to a python object

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle

I have a requirement of saving my custom tensorflow model which has a mix of python objects and tf tensors included within. I want something that can help serialize this custom tensorflow python class. Something like `pickle.dumps(custom_tf_python_class)` so that I can just load it like `custom_tf_python_class = pickle.load(fp)`. I have tried `pickle`, `dill`, and `cloudpickle`, but I always get the `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`.

I am not, necessarily, limited to pickle, any module/library that can help me serialize this object will do? Maybe I need to implement a custom `__reduce__` function but I am not sure how to work with that?

I am using `tensorflow==2.11.0`

My sample code

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        self.input_shape = input_dim
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim, input_shape=(input_dim,))
    
    @property
    def input_shape(self):
        return self._input_shape
    
    @input_shape.setter
    def input_shape(self, value):
        self._input_shape = value
        
    @property
    def name(self):
        return "Something"
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}-{super().__repr__()}"

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.dense(inputs)

class MyModuleWithSubModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sub_module = MyModule(input_dim=2, output_dim=1)
    
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.sub_module(inputs)
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return "SomethingElse"
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}-{super().__repr__()}"

main_module = MyModuleWithSubModule()
```

Comment: Just follow the guide here  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20formats%20you,you%20use%20model.save()%20.

Comment: It's not a keras model. Its a python class which contains python objects as well as tensorflow tensor included! I want a way where I can serialize this class so I can get back my python objects as well as my tensors (I am fine if they are converted to tensors)